# Django not saving timezone info. How to store this correctly

Tags: django, datetime, timezone

I've got this code in an ajax view:

```
    now = pytz.timezone("America/Guayaquil").localize(datetime.now())
    print("HOUR: %s" % now.hour)        
    new_timer = WorkTime.objects.create(inicio=now)
    print("new_timer.id: %s" % new_timer.id)
    print("new_timer.hour %s" % new_timer.inicio.hour)
```

it prints this:

```
HOUR: 18
new_timer.id: 16
new_timer.hour 18
```

"inicio" is a DateTimeField. Then I access the same object from a regular view to render an html, this is the code:

```
last_timer = TiempoEmpresarial.objects.filter(final__isnull=True).last()
print("Timer object:")
print(last_timer.id)  # is it the same obj?
print(last_timer.inicio.hour)
```

it prints this:

```
Timer object:
16
23
```

It is the same object, id=16. But it has a different hour. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django stores UTC time in the database, when rendering, `TIME_ZONE` and `USE_TZ` in `setting.py` decides the timezone.

In your case, try `print(last_timer.inicio)`, you would see something like `datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 17, 3, 17, 6, 760770, tzinfo=<UTC>)`.

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly create `now` in the `America/Guayaquil` timezone, which is 5 hours before `UTC`.

When you save the model to the database, the `DateTimeField` is converted to and stored in `UTC`, as described in the [timezone documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/): "When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database."

When you later retrieve that value, you get the `UTC` version, hence the 5-hour difference.